# How to Capture Java -jar command's OS Output in Linux?

Tags: java, linux, shell, unix, jar

I am running java -jar xyz.jar command on the linux terminal. I have both system.out.println statements and System.exit statements in the code.

how to capture the system.exit or output to the OS on the linux? do i need to prepare a linux script for this?

Comment: just redirect `jar whatever ... > redirect.txt`

Comment: What do you mean by "to the OS"? Do you want to write it to a file so that other program/process can use it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This may be off-topic for SO.

You just redirect it:

```
java -jar xyz.jar > the_file_to_output
```

If you used `System.err` output as well as `System.out` output and wanted to redirect both, it's a tiny bit more complicated because you need to redirect *out* to the file and *then* redirect *error* to *out*:

```
java -jar xyz.jar > the_file_to_output 2>&1
```

The `2>&1` thing is what redirects *error* (standard stream #2) to *out* (standard stream #1). Note that the order matters, you have to do that *after* redirecting *out* to the file.

Comment: I just could not find the duplicate for that. But of course this is the way.

Comment: java -jar xyz.jar > the_file_to_output 2>&1
This helped me.

Answer (score 2):

Java works as any other command.

If you want standard output (or error output) you can work with usual I/O operators:  > 2> >> |

```
java -jar xyz.jar > output.file
java -jar xyz.jar | sort | less
```

For getting System.exit value you have special variable $?

```
java -jar xyz.jar
echo $?
```

To get more info [Exit status](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exit-status.html) and [I/O redirection](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html)

Comment: @AKC: `$?` has nothing to do with capturing *output*. If it's the exit code you wanted, though, that's what you need. (Don't forget to mark an answer correct if it answers your question.)